# Where can I see my flag count / history?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

Is there a section or page that lists my flag count and / or history?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Open your profile page and click on your "helpful flags" count in the "Activity" tab. It will provide you with a detailed breakdown of number of flags, helpful flags, disputed flags, etc., plus a history of all non-comment flags.

[image: A user's profile page, on the "Activity" tab with "helpful flags" highlighted.]

Answer (score 19):

You can see it on your profile page. There is no link for helpful flag, at the beginning; when you have your first helpful flag, you can see the link in your profile as follows, which is under the profile views.

[image: screenshot]

Whenever you click on the count link, it will show you the full summary.

You can see the history of your flags on the right-hand side; it displays the following information:

- The total number of flags you raised
- The number of flags waiting for review (this is generally done by 10K users, and moderators)
- The number of flags deemed helpful
- The number of declined flags
- The number of disputed flags

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have yet any helpful flag, you can use the method explained here:

[How can I see my active flags with no prior helpful flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245811/how-can-i-see-my-active-flags-with-no-prior-helpful-flags)