# Suspected suspended user posting under a new account

Tags: support, flags, account-suspension, sock-puppets

In answering a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10848652/920242), I noticed a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10613715/920242) with a very similar name and similar content, from another user.  The question I answered was from an account created three days ago ([RKP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1425709/rkp)); the previous one was from a suspended user ([Rohan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086960/rohan)).  There's no bio for either of them, but the locations seem to match (my Google-Fu tells me that Vadodara and Baroda are actually the same place).

How can I (i.e., an SO user, not a mod or anything) tell if this is one user with multiple accounts?  And if I suspect it, should I report it?  If so, how?

Sorry to make my first Meta post about this, but I wasn't sure what to do.  :o/

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention. No real point in making a meta topic about it.

Comment: Flag the question, select "other" and explain the situation in the text field - the moderators have better tools to investigate this.

Comment: Thanks, all.  Done and done, and we'll see what the mods do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#flagging) for notification for multiple account of an user is very easy, see the following steps,

1. Open any question or answer from any one of the account.
2. click on the flag link below the question/answer.

   > [image]
3. Select the Other option and write his profile link of another account stating that this could be another SO account of this user.

   > [image]
4. Click on Flag Button and reporting to moderator is done.

In case if none of the user's account has question/answer ( which is not possible most of the time ) you can report here on http://meta.stackoverflow.com or you can email to Stack Overflow team on team@stackoverflow.com

**Warning:** Flagging is taken as very serious.

see, what happens when an Flags comes [helpful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132040/173001).

Comment: Thanks for this -- nice and clear, particularly with the images, and I pretty-much used your wording.

Comment: @karaken12 you welcome, happy to help you :) and support the moderators to keep the site clean from this bogus accounts :)