# User with 2 profiles answering his own question

Tags: support, status-completed, accepted-answer, user-accounts

I happened to be looking at a question and got interested in the user profiles of:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133846/hai-truong-info-tech
and 
https://stackoverflow.com/users/840461/ha1tru0n9
because of the similar names.

Looking at ha1tru0n9, it seems like he exists merely to answer Hai Truong's questions. This seems dodgy, but I'm not sure if it's forbidden, so I thought I'd draw it to the moderators attention.

Comment: FYI; in the future, you can simply flag one of the questions/answers of one of the users and include your report there. You can include the URLs for each profile in the flag; use the 'Other' type.

Comment: See [Possible sockpuppet - What's the procedure?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127467)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Looking at ha1tru0n9, it seems like he exists merely to answer Hai Truong's questions. This seems dodgy, but I'm not sure if it's forbidden, so I thought I'd draw it to the moderators attention.

Yes, it is forbidden to create multiple accounts (called *sock puppets*) to answer your own (or in fact anyone's) questions in order to deposit votes for a reputation boost.<sup>1</sup> As mentioned by the answer to

[Possible sockpuppet - What's the procedure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127467/possible-sockpuppet-whats-the-procedure)

... the optimal course of action is to [flag one of the user's posts](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) for moderator attention, which sends a message directly to us so we can handle it as quickly as possible.

That said, we've handled the case, since you've posted here on meta. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Not only is reputation quite easily earned through honest and sincere involvement with the community, but it is also not necessary to create a different account to answer your own question.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Would have just done that, except didn't think to search for Sock Puppet.

Answer (score 4):

Flag the opvoted questions for moderator attention. Moderators have additional tools to determine if this is indeed a sock-puppet account.

Answer (score 2):

It is good that you have reported here on meta.

The other way you can do it ,flag either of their accounts with the link of the second profile's link.

Also you can write an email to team@stackoverflow.com with such details as you mentioned here, this way the direct links to the profiles remains hidden.

For more information, visit this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134211/173001).

Comment: I'd say the preferred way is via flagging, not coming here to Meta.

Comment: @UristMcBobby yes, agree but reporting on meta for those who is not familiar with the flags, after all flags are taken very seriously.

Comment: why downvote ...?