# User keeps creating duplicate IDs to avoid accepting answers

Tags: discussion

[How to properly run ActionBarSherlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633806/runnin-sherlock-action-bar/11633896#11633896)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602197/action-bar-view

[how to improve action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601542/how-to-improve-action-bar/11601587#11601587)

All three of these are posted by the same user, who is just using different aliases. He does so, once his accept rate goes down. He'd rather do this than accept answers.

Also, it isn't that he does not know the procedure, as he did accept my answer on one question. Shouldn't **such** users be warned?

Comment: How do you know it's the same user?

Comment: Rather, I think the user is avoiding a posting ban. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1534147/naseeb-sheoran has a terrible track record.

Comment: you can do like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134211/173001)

Comment: Harassing the user via comments about their accept rate is inappropriate and frowned upon.  See [Is it appropriate to comment on people's accept rate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23321/is-it-appropriate-to-comment-on-peoples-accept-rate/23326#23326)  Also, you can just flag one of the users posts for moderator attention, explaining you think they're maliciously creating multiple accounts.

Comment: You are not required to accept an answer. But creating duplicate accounts is not advisable.

Comment: Okay. I was just asking him to accept answers, rather than commenting on answers saying "it worked". Also, I know it is the same user, because he is posting the same code!

Comment: Unless it's the exact same user, closing this as a duplicate makes no sense.

Comment: Ah, [suspended](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1534147/naseeb-sheoran) and all accounts merged now. Nice find, @Dark.