# All users should see their flag history as soon as they make a flag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, declined-flags, flag-history

This is described in [more detail here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132018/where-can-i-see-my-flag-count-history). Rather than waiting for the first flag to be positively handled, as soon as a user makes a flag, they should be able to see a history of the flags they have raised and their current status. Right now, if a user is making flags that get declined, they have no way to see that their flags were reviewed and rejected by moderators and which ones are still pending review and therefore don't have a way to learn. This would remove some of the mystery of the flagging system and hopefully allow users that *want to improve their participation* a way to do it.

Comment: Would be less annoying if it only happened if you have declined flags you haven't seen. If you're still flagging well, move along

Comment: Perhaps something like "Flags: 4 (0 Helpful)"?

Comment: @Jim That would work, too. I'm not sure what the formatting should be. I just know that I've raised flags on a site and I don't know if they have been handled (or if they are pending) and if they were dismissed as unhelpful, what the reasoning is.

Comment: per my recollection, previous discussion of a [particular bug with flagging summary links](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tPqMh.jpg "ancient screen shot") has been pretty quickly "resolved by design", by making [meta-tag:flag-weight] invisible. Wonder how it will be this time

Comment: @gnat Flag weight is still hidden. And there is a trigger for showing people their flag history. It's just that the current trigger is bad.

Comment: It tells you stats in your *profile*, but **they should go farther and show each flag individually.** This is driving me **CRAZY!!!!!!** I wish they would fix this.

Answer (score 7):

This was implemented back in [July 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261787/164200). The link to view the flag history is available on the profile page even if none of the flags have been accepted yet.