# Where are my closed votes on questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, flag-history

I read *[Where can I see my flag count / history?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132018/where-can-i-see-my-flag-count-history/132040#132040)*.

However this only shows the flags I've done on comments. I've <s>flagged questions</s> voted questions to be closed as duplicates, but I don't see them!

I do some of them, but not the last few months:

[image]

Even though today, I marked *[Can the "as" keyword be used to explicitly state a type for key/values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46715740/can-the-as-keyword-be-used-to-explicitly-state-a-type-for-key-values)* as a duplicate...

Comment: It does not only show comment flags, it shows all flags.

Comment: @Servy I don't see mine. I only see it for comments. EDIT: Correction The last flag for duplicate I see belongs to: **Apr 19**. However I have flagged several questions as duplicate since then...Is there any reason I'm not seeing my newer flags? I do so other recent flags, but they are NOT related to my duplicate flags...

Comment: You have not flagged a question for closure since then.  You've *voted* for closure since then, as that's when you earned the privilege to vote to close.  The flag history does not show close votes, only flags cast.

Comment: @Servy I see. Thanks. So is there any other way to see your close votes history?

Comment: @Honey [votes tab in your user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=closure). Agree it's bit confusing that what used to be flag turns all by itself to close vote at some point, but that's just how things work. :)

Comment: @Honey may I know how you raised a NAA flag for a comment?

Comment: @redhand: It was almost certainly an answer when flagged, and then converted into a comment.

Comment: @ale in the image which OP uploaded, the **post** filter is active and the title in the image also says helpful post flags. It won't list comment flags.